# Matching Strings from two columns from two different tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I have created two tables, lets call them table a and table b.

Table A consists of one column of strings called domainType

Table B consists of one column of strings which are substrings to table A's column (called topLevelDomain)

```
CREATE TABLE a ( rank int, name text, domainType text )

CREATE TABLE b ( topLevelDomain text, domainDescription text)
```

table a:

```
 rank     name      domainType
 1        a          com
 2        b          co jp
 3        c          co cn
```

table b:

```
topLevelDomain    domainDescription
com               country1
in                country2
cn                country3
...
jp                country30
```

I want to list the most popular descriptions(countries) according to the rank of the domainType
to show this:

Desired result:

```
country1 -------> since rank is 1 (in table a)
country30 ------> since rank is 2 (in table a)
country2 --------> since rank is 3 (in table a)
```

I'm having trouble 'relating' the topLevelDomain column with the domainType column and returning the descriptions with the top rank corresponding to the domainType. I hope this makes sense! please let me know to add anymore information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables with the use of the operator `LIKE`:

```
select b.domaindescription
from b left join a
on  concat(' ', a.domaintype, ' ') like concat('% ', b.topleveldomain, ' %')
order by case when a.domaintype is null then 1 else 0 end, a.rank
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8juzzPYy3pcpdYYDeYeYb6/0).
Results:

```
| domaindescription |
| ----------------- |
| country1          |
| country30         |
| country3          |
| country2          |
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! the concat part really helped, however, when it comes to the ORDER BY part, i get the following error: "ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list".

Comment: You can check the demo where there is no such error.

Comment: I followed the according demo but when I try to excute it, it states that "The column name topLevelDomain was not found in this ResultSet." *EDIT* minor mistake, all fixed!!